# Error occurs when try to "EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell" commands through web request from database trigger to create text file locally

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, database-trigger, xp-cmdshell

**Requirement**: I want to create text file from SQL-Server DB trigger using cmdshell commands(mentioned in title).

**Scenarios**:

**S1**:
When I am trying to execute cmdshell command(mentioned in title) from trigger to create text file and write some content in it, it will execute properly and file is getting created.

**S2**:
When I am trying to call and execute the same scenario **S1** from windows Server 2016 WebAPI service through IIS, we are getting following error in Event Viewer.

[image: Event Viewer error.]

Comment: Not sure if this log depends on this, but xp_cmdshell is disabled by default. Did you enable it on the failing server?

Answer (score 1):

`xp_CmdShell` needs a [windows account](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) mapping to successfully execute. If you are logged in with a user that has the `sysadmin` role (I'm guessing this is your first scenario), the account used will be the one for SQL Server Service account.

If the user isn't `sysadmin` (this should be the IIS user), then it will impersonate the configured account for a special credential called `##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##`, which you need to configure.

To set this account up, use the SP [sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xp-cmdshell-proxy-account-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), for example:

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'DOMAIN\SQLServerCMDProxy','sdfh%dkc93vcMt0';
```

You can check this mapping with:

```
select * from sys.credentials
```

[image]

You will also need to grant the execute command on `xp_cmdshell` procedure if you didn't already:

```
GRANT EXEC ON xp_cmdshell TO 'IISUser'
```

And you can test if it works correctly by impersonating the login with a user with enough priviledges:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'IISUser' -- Shift priviledges to this login for the current session

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe'; -- Try to execute the xp_cmdshell

REVERT -- Revert to the previous login
```

---

**PD:** Be very careful when enabling the use of `xp_cmdshell` on your SQL Server as it might open security holes, specially when giving permissions to uncontrolled logins. Even if you encapsulate a particular call in an SP, there are workarounds that the user can do to bypass and execute `xp_cmdshell` directly. The proper way to do this is via certificate signing with a custom login.